# Set Scroll bar width in Typescript based UWP App

Tags: javascript, uwp

I am working on a UWP App in which I want to modify the Scroll bar width using javascript and HTML. is there any way to do it

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}

Comment: Also i tried to clip some width of the scroll bar but that is also giving bad UI experience as top and bottom arrows in the scroll are also getting clipped

Comment: @TheTanic do u have any other suggestions

Comment: Where is the scroll bar? Whose scroll bar? Could you post more details and clarify your requirement?